# How does proximal centriole of human sperm function?

Tags: human-biology, reproduction

I've read that the human's unfertilized oocyte ( stuck at metaphase 2 of meiosis ) lacks centrioles and that it completes meiosis 2 after fertilization as sperm gives its proximal centriole. Then what about the centrioles required for mitosis of zygote?? How does proximal centriole function?